# Crear relación uno a varios en android room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Estoy tratando de crear un proyecto de android con room y SQLite, pero no me queda del todo claro la implementación de llaves foraneas en mis modelos, son 2 uno de registro de un modelo de lotes de ganado y otro sobre el historial de cambios que han sucedido en ese lote, en teoría la relación sería de que en un lote de ganado puede existir X cantidad de historial de cambios o sucesos del mismo

El código de ambos modelos sería el siguiente:
Modelo de lotes de ganado

```
@Entity(tableName = "lotes_table")
public class LotesModel implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name= "idLote")
    private Integer idLote;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name= "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tamano")
    private double tamano;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "estado")
    private String estado;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "video")
    String video;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "imagen")
    String imagen; //byte [] imagen

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fechaCreacion")
    @TypeConverters(DataConverter.class)
    Date fechaCreacion;
}
```

Modelo de historicos

```
@Entity(tableName = "historicos_table",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = LotesModel.class,
        parentColumns = "idLote",
        childColumns = "idWhitLote",
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE))
public class HistoricosModel implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name= "idHistorico")
    private Integer idHistorico;

    private Integer idWhitLote;
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fechaCreacion")
    @TypeConverters(DataConverter.class)
    Date fechaCreacion;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fechaFinal")
    @TypeConverters(DataConverter.class)
    Date fechaFinal;

}
```

A decir verdad no se si esta es la manera de crear una llave foranea, he visto distintas formas pero no se cual es la correcta

Answer (score 2):

según la documentación de Room, las relaciono de uno a muchos debería ser la siguiente:

**Definicion**

> En las relaciones de uno a varios entre dos entidades, cada instancia de la entidad principal corresponde a cero o más instancias de la entidad secundaria, pero cada instancia de la entidad secundaria **solo puede corresponder una instancia de la entidad principal**.

Ejemplo:

> Primero, crea una clase para cada una de las dos entidades. La entidad secundaria debe incluir una variable que haga referencia a la clave primaria de la entidad principal.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey public long userId;
    public String name;
    public int age;
}

@Entity
public class Playlist {
    @PrimaryKey public long playlistId;
    public long userCreatorId;
    public String playlistName;
}
```

> A fin de consultar la lista de usuarios y las listas de reproducción correspondientes, primero debes modelar la relación de uno a varios entre las dos entidades. Para ello, crea una clase de datos nueva en la que cada instancia tenga una instancia de la entidad principal y una lista de todas las instancias de entidades secundarias correspondientes. Agrega la anotación @Relation a la instancia de la entidad secundaria, y asigna a parentColumn el nombre de la columna de clave primaria de la entidad principal y a entityColumn el nombre de la columna de la entidad secundaria que hace referencia a la clave primaria de la entidad principal.

```
public class UserWithPlaylists {
    @Embedded public User user;
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "userId",
         entityColumn = "userCreatorId"
    )
    public List<Playlist> playlists;
}
```

> Por último, agrega un método a la clase DAO que muestre todas las instancias de la clase de datos que vincula la entidad principal con la secundaria. Este método requiere que Room ejecute dos consultas, así que agrega la anotación @Transaction al método para asegurarte de que toda la operación se realice automáticamente.

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM User")
public List<UserWithPlaylists> getUsersWithPlaylists();
```

Ahora para tu caso tendríamos algo como :

```
@Entity(tableName = "lotes_table")
public class LotesModel{
    @PrimaryKey public long idLote;
}

@Entity(tableName = "historicos_table")
public class HistoricosModel{
    @PrimaryKey public long idHistorico;
    public long idWhitLote;
}
```

Y la relación, de uno a muchos seria :

```
public class LotesWithHistorico {
    @Embedded public LotesModel lotesModel;
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "idLote",
         entityColumn = "idWhitLote"
    )
    public List<HistoricosModel> historicosModel;
}
```

Espero te ayude :)