# Room Database: KotlinNullPointerException cuando guardo un array de objectos

Tags: android, kotlin, studio

Tengo una base de datos en el que guarda un objecto, el cual dentro tiene un ArrayList de otro objeto. Se guarda perfecto, y los obtengo de la base de datos perfecto tambien. El problema esta que si imprimo el id de la session (Sessions class) me lo imprime bien (ej: Log.d("test", sessions.id) pero si quiero imprimir el nombre de un producto (dentro de SessionProduct class) de esa session (ej: Log.d("test",session.sessionProducts[0].name) me devuelve "KotlinNullPointerException" y crashea) Aclaro por las dudas: La API me devuelve bien, no se si el problema esta en como lo guardo, o en como lo estoy seteando aca:

```
@Entity
data class Sessions (
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("id") var id: String,
    @Embedded
    @SerializedName("items") var sessionProducts: ArrayList<SessionProduct>? = ArrayList() // El problema esta aca
) : Serializable
```

Y sessionProducts:

```
@Entity
data class SessionProduct (
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id") var id: String,
    @SerializedName("name") var name: String
) : Serializable
```

(Corte las dos clases para que no sea tan extenso)

Use tanto un TypeConverter como no, y en ambos casos me tiro nullPointer tambien

```
@Database(entities = [Sessions::class, SessionProduct::class], version = 4, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(SessionsProductsConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase(){
```

Repito: El problema esta cuando quiero obtener lo que hay dentro de ArrayList

```
@Dao
interface PendingSessionsDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM sessions")
    fun getAllPendingSessions(): List<Sessions>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun addAllPendingSessions(sessions: List<Sessions>)

    @Update
    fun updatePendingSessions(sessions: List<Sessions>)

    @Query("DELETE FROM sessions")
    fun deleteAllTable()

}
```

Aca es la funcion donde yo guardo:

```
fun addPendingSessions(context: Context, sessions: List<Sessions>){

        class AddPendingSessions : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {
                AppDatabase.getPendingSessionsDatabaseInstance(context).pendingSessionsDao().addAllPendingSessions(sessions)
                return null
            }

            override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
                super.onPostExecute(result)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Pending sessions saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }
        AddPendingSessions().execute()
    }
```

Y para testear si se guarda bien hago esto:

```
Log.d("TestingPicking", sessionId.id) // Esto si me lo imprime bien en la consola
for (product in sessionId.sessionProducts!!)
    Log.d("TestingPicking", product.name) // Y cuando quiere hacer esto tira NullPointer
```

He intentado todo lo que vi en internet y no pude solucionarlo. Tal vez alguien le haya pasado lo mismo y sabe como solucionarlo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: No se ve que estés generando alguna instancia de SessionProduct, podrías agregar el código dónde le asignas los sessionProduct a Sessions?, creo que ahí puede estar tu problema

Comment: Hola aqui tengo una referencia ->
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/369275/crear-relación-uno-a-varios-en-android-room/370156#370156